# Passing bash script variables to .yml file for use as child and subdirectories

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to write a bash script `test-bash.sh` that will pass arguments from a txt file `test-text.txt` to a .yml file `test-yaml.yml`, to be used as child and subdirectory arguments (by that I mean e.g. `/path/to/XXXX/child/` and `/path/to/XXXX` where XXXX is the argument passed from the .sh script.

I'm really struggling to wrap my head around a way to do this so here is a small example of what I'm trying to achieve:

test-text.txt:

```
folder1
folder2
```

test-yaml.yml:

```
general:
  XXXX: argument_from_bash_script
  rawdatadir: '/some/data/directory/XXXX'
  input: '/my/input/directory/XXXX/input'
  output: '/my/output/directory/XXXX/output'
```

test-bash.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="test-text.txt"    
FOLDERS=$(cat $FILENAME)

for FOLDER in $FOLDERS
do
        ~ pass FOLDER to .yml file as argument ~
        ~ run stuff using edited .yml file ~
done
```

Where the code enclosed in '~' symbols is pseudo code.

---

I've found [this page](https://www.starkandwayne.com/blog/bashing-your-yaml/) on using `export`, would this work in the looping case above or am I barking up the wrong tree with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `envsubst` solve your problem?

For example, if I have a `test-yaml.yml` that contains `$foo`:

```sh
cat test-yaml.yml
```

output:

```
general:
  $foo: argument_from_bash_script
  rawdatadir: '/some/data/directory/$foo'
  input: '/my/input/directory/$foo/input'
  output: '/my/output/directory/$foo/output'
```

You can replace `$foo` inside `test-yaml.yml` with shell variable `$foo` by `envsubst`:

```sh
export foo=123
envsubst < test-yaml.yml
```

output:

```
general:
  123: argument_from_bash_script
  rawdatadir: '/some/data/directory/123'
  input: '/my/input/directory/123/input'
  output: '/my/output/directory/123/output'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; what is the λ in this case? And are the top and bottom code snippets variations of two different yaml files? Or is the top file the the .txt file which then feeds into the .yml code snippet below? Sorry, I'm very new to this!

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. `λ` is just my command line prompt. I'll modify the answer later.

Comment: Quick further question, once you have substituted the variables into the test-yaml.yml file, how do you then use that yaml file in the `~ run stuff using edited .yml file ~` section without it defaulting to reading the original unedited .yml file which will contain literal strings like `rawdatadir: '/some/data/directory/123'` as opposed to the desired `rawdatadir: '/some/data/directory/argument_from_bash_script'` ? If that makes sense